# What triggers an AI empire?

Tags: spore

AI empires are created around you as you go, but exactly what actions will cause an empire to be created and go active? Right now I'm forced to either ally or wipe out (take that, you stranger-distrusting bigots) any empire that I meet on my travels, to avoid having to hunt them down later and discover that I need to conquer 30-odd star systems to stop them attacking me or my allies. I would like to know if I can move around the galaxy without peppering it with annoying life.

Comment: You can create empires yourself by random populating a livable planet with creatures. But that is all i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploring creates the AI empires.

Being near an AI empire causes them to be active. AI empires that are far enough away from you will go dormant until you get close to their territory again.

In Spore, I find it fairly easy to just outrun non-Grox enemy empires--- as long as I don't have any ally empires. Allies drag you into all sorts of trouble, like having to run back to their area to laser a few sick wild life or because they are under attack from Grox or Pirates.

AI empires that aren't at war with you can be bribed into liking you or at least being neutral. So trading spice and bribing AI is always a possible tactic as well.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from randomly generated empires, you can also uplift a species on a planet by placing  [monoliths](http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Monolith). This action also causes a huge reputation(+50) with that species once they advance to space stage.